# A nifty way to squash an array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

The array is:

```
arr = [["lorem", 10], ["ipsum", 20], ["lorem", 15], ["dolor", 5], ["dolor", 10] ...]
```

What is the nifty way to merge it, to have:

```
[["lorem", 25], ["ipsum", 20], ["dolor", 15]]
```

- same string values should me merged along with integers they have (`lorem` in `arr` has `10` and `15` so result is one `lorem` with `25`)
- they should be sorted by the integer value (25..20..15 in the example above)

Comment: Show us your effort, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a quick a dirty way to go about this

```
arr = [["lorem", 10], ["ipsum", 20], ["lorem", 15], ["dolor", 5], ["dolor", 10]]
arr.dup.group_by(&:shift).map{|k,v|[k,v.flatten.reduce(:+)]}.sort_by{|a|-a.last}
#=>[["lorem", 25], ["ipsum", 20], ["dolor", 15]]
```

It will dup the array, because shift is destructive, and then it will group by the first value creating a `Hash` like:

```
{"lorem"=>[[10],[15]],"ipsum"=>[[20]],"dolor"=>[[5],[10]]}
```

Then it will `map` and call `flatten` and `reduce` on the value array.

Could also be done using `each_with_object`

```
ar.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k,v),obj| obj[k] += v}.sort_by{|_,v| -v}
#=>[["lorem", 25], ["ipsum", 20], ["dolor", 15]]
```

Comment: `; obj` is unnecessary.

Comment: @cremno edited thank you. I was messing around with inject instead e.g.`arr.inject(Hash.new(0)){|obj,(k,v)| obj[k] += v;obj}.sort_by{|_,v| -v}` in which case `;obj` would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
arr.group_by { |vals| vals[0] }.map { |(k, v)| [k, v.map { |x| x[1] }.reduce(:+)] }.sort_by { |a| -a[1] }
```

Output

```
=> [["lorem", 25], ["ipsum", 20], ["dolor", 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.to_enum.with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k, v), h| h[k] += v}.sort_by(&:last).reverse
# => [["lorem", 25], ["ipsum", 20], ["dolor", 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).reduce(&:+)] }
```